# Dynamics CRM 2013: Distribute CampaignActivity with custom channel

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

Sorry in advance for my bad english :p

I'm trying to distribute Campaign Activity using a new channel that I called "SMS",

1. I added the SMS option in the channeltypecode picklist,
2. and updated the boutton (on rubbon) of distrubution action, and make it call a
   new javascript function (ActionToDistributeSMS) if channel is SMS,
3. and I developped a plugin (C#) to destribute the CampaignActivity
4. the ActionToDistributeSMS() function will lance the plugin

*...
(DistributeCampaignActivityResponse)service.Execute(distrubuteCampaign); //code from the plugin
...*

my problem is that I recieve this error: "An invalid object type was specified for distributing activities"
Detailled error: "Only activities appointments, emails, faxes, letters and phone calls are supported."

**how can I add SMS to supported channel types ?**

Answer (score 0):

The custom channel is not supported.

You can't distribute activities on campaigns if the channels are not the natives ones.

The only way to achieve this is extending a plug-in/custom that retrieve the list members and create manually the activities, but this like a new way to distribute campaigns instead the native one.